# We broke all the river dams. Does it reverse environmental damage/climate change?

Tags: environment, weather, water, rivers

A group of humans, called the Dams, became sick of political feuds involving water. They were completely tired of the wasteful wars the countries fought for  water resources. These wars had created a lot of damn dams which displaced local populace, affected the downstream flow, destroyed ecology, and whatnot.

These tired Agents of Damnation decided to tackle the root of the problem: they came to the conclusion that they needed to un-dam all the damn artificial dams on the planet. They also needed to make massive plantations of quick growing trees and shrubs across vast swathes of land downstream on all Damm(n)ed rivers.

Now 100 years have passed since operation ''Damn the Dams'' has been completed. All the river dams across the world are broken open. How would the local weather and ecology be affected? Will it really help restore ecological balance or will it be just a damn failure?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood properly but, as a summary, are you asking **"If we planted lots of trees would it make the water return?"**

Comment: Why does it say that you are the person who edited the question?  These are the edits that I made.

Comment: @NateDukes, I reviewed your edits. I amended it slightly but looking at the edit history it's got all confusing. I also narrowed the focus from climate down to weather. Climate changes are a very broad regional or global sort of question. I tried to shift the focus just to local weather and environmental changes of those areas near the Damned Dams. If someone can then take an answer further to incorporate the large climatic influences...great! Feel free to change it back if you don't agree.

Comment: If dams are your problem, what do you hope to accomplish by rebuilding new ones out of trees after the old ones go away? IMHO that would be an expensive waste of time with no net effect

Answer (score 2):

You would see an effect on freshwater ecology:

- migrating fish will have free run of the river
- natural flooding and drying cycles will occur more often, allowing fish to spawn more often (they often like eating flooded plants on floodplains)

You'll also see native riverine plant species become more prevalent, as their seed cycles often depend on flood cycles.

But planting quick growing species across large areas will likely destroy the ecological improvements you wanted. You've just brought in weeds.

You'll have wrecked human economy. No hydropower, and unreliable irrigation. So the local human populations will likely trash the environment elsewhere as they try to maintain existence with fewer resources.

You won't see any climate change. Dams and trees don't really do that on a useful scale.